# Getting data from component

Tags: typescript, angular7

I have a problem with getting data from component. Here is the snippet of my code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthoritiesConst } from 'app/shared/util/authorities-const';
import { IMenuItem } from 'app/shared/services/navigation.service';
import { ProjectComponent } from '../../module-cpms/views/project/project.component';
import { IProject } from 'app/module-cpms/model/project.model';
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-appmenu',
    templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild(ProjectComponent) project: any;


    menus: IMenuItem[];
    projectDetail: IProject;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.menus = [
            {
                name: 'title',
                state: ['/project'],
            },
            {
                name: 'company',
                state: ['/company'],
                roles: [
                    AuthoritiesConst.ROLE_ADMIN,
                    AuthoritiesConst.ROLE_BO,
                    AuthoritiesConst.ROLE_CS,
                    AuthoritiesConst.ROLE_CA,
                ],
            },
        ];


    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.projectDetail = this.project.project;
        console.log(this.project);
    }

    getMenusItem() {
        return this.menus;
    }
}
```

And here is the parent component for collecting data:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(({ project }) => {
      this.project = project;
    });

  }
```

But on `menu.components.ts` above gives me undefined. What did i do wrong ? Any advice ? What i exactly want is when user change the route some header element get some information from the parent component. But when i try to console `project` from parent it's gives me datas correctly. But when i pass this datas to child `menu.components` it gives `undefined`.

Comment: `ViewChild` is supposed to be used in the parent component to get the children component reference, not the other way around. From your description it sounds to me like you are trying to do it the wrong way. Am I misunderstanding something ?

Comment: @Morphyish i am trying to get some data to menu component from project component.

Comment: Then you should probably use an `@Input` and not a `@ViewChild`, if the menu component is used inside the project component.

Comment: @Morphyish i am using menu component as in main component not inside of the project. In layout component i declare `<jhi-appmenu></jhi-appmenu>`.

Comment: You should probably put the `route.data` subscriber inside the main component, and pass the value to the menu using a `@Input`. Or you could listen to `this.route.data` from inside the menu component directly ?

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply listen to your route from the menu component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-appmenu',
    templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    menus: IMenuItem[];
    projectDetail: IProject;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.menus = [
            {
                name: 'title',
                state: ['/project'],
            },
            {
                name: 'company',
                state: ['/company'],
                roles: [
                    AuthoritiesConst.ROLE_ADMIN,
                    AuthoritiesConst.ROLE_BO,
                    AuthoritiesConst.ROLE_CS,
                    AuthoritiesConst.ROLE_CA,
                ],
            },
        ];


        this.route.data.subscribe(({ project }) => {
          this.projectDetail = project;
        });
    }

    getMenusItem() {
        return this.menus;
    }
}
```

Inject the `ActivatedRoute` inside your menu component (I'm assuming that's what the `route` is inside your project component, I haven't used Angular in a while. If it's not, just use whatever you are currently using inside the project component).

Listen for data changes, exactly as you were doing inside the project component inside the `ngOnInit`.

Remove the `@ViewChild`, and `ngAfterViewInit` from the menu, those parts aren't necessary anymore.

Comment: Thanks i will try this.

Comment: Well it is same.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the part of your application router corresponding to the projects route ?